# How to connect to homepage after creating it with a python webframework (hyde) from an other machine in the same network?

Tags: server, configuration, networking, webserver, websites

I created a website on a server with [hyde](http://hyde.github.com/). After installing hyde on a Ubuntu machine, I followed these steps:

**Temrinal:**

```
$ hyde -s /path/to/mysite create
$ cd /path/to/mysite
$ hyde gen
$ hyde serve
```

The server starts, and shows no problems(,yet ^^").

The thing is: The server has no gui, and there fore no browser (except terminal browsers). Therefore I want to connect to this created page from another ubuntu machine (my PC I work with), which is in the same network.

I read up about the [documentation](http://hyde.github.com/commands) of hyde and I got this information, to specify the ip and the port the site should be available on:

- `-a ADDRESS`, `--address ADDRESS` The address to serve the website. Optional - defaults to localhost
- `-p PORT`, `--port PORT` The port to serve the website. Optional - defaults to 8080
- The following command will serve the website at http://localhost:8181.

**Terminal:**

```
$ cd ~/test
$ hyde serve -p 8181
```

Which are the settings I have to set on the Ubuntu GUI-less server, to get me mysite reachable from the my Ubuntu machine which has a GUI?

Perhaps I should mention, that both server are in the intranet of the company where I work.

This is only a test for me to get this running and to be able to start to throw a website together. Later on I want to get this site running with apache, and not using the provided webserver of hyde. But that is another questin, I think...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give hyde the external ip of the server, not localhost which is limited to the machine itself.

To get the external ip, run `ifconfig | grep "inet addr"`

```
egil@mutter:~$ ifconfig | grep "inet addr"
          inet addr:192.168.10.10  Bcast:192.168.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
```

The `inet addr` on the same line as with `Bcast` and `Mask` is the one you need to start hyde with.

Comment: I'll try that as soon as I get my hands on the server again. Which port do you recommend?

Comment: Any port over 1024 will do, so you might as well stick with the default 8080 as it's marked as a registered port for alternative http traffic by IANA. See http://www.iana.org/assignments/port-numbers.